# fetching related data using the same uid

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

i trying to read related data from **dataorder** which related using **userID** from **datauser**.

```
private void cobacoba(){
        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("datauser");
        databaseUser.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String nama = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataUser.class).getUserId();
                hey.setText("haloo "+nama);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

i use code above to read data from **datauser** but how do i read the related data on **dataorder** ?
i try the same way to read the **idOrder** from **dataorder** but the value always **null**. can some one help please ?

```
FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final String userid = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseOrder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dataorder");
        databaseOrder.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final String idorder = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataOrder.class).getIdOrder();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(idorder)){
                    status.setText(idorder);
                    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    final String userid = user.getUid();
                    final DatabaseReference databaseOrder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dataorder");
                    databaseOrder.child(userid).child(idorder).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String haritanggal = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataOrder.class).getHaritanggalOrder();
                            String jamlapangan = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataOrder.class).getLapanganjamOrder();
                            idordeer.setText("Order ID = "+idorder);
                            jamtanggal.setText("Tanggal dan Waktu = "+jamlapangan+" Tanggal "+haritanggal);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    status.setText("no current order");
                }
                status.setText("id anda= "+idorder+" ....."); //<<<id value always null, why ?????
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

using code above, i discover **idOrder** always null thats why i cannot access the data inside it, because i don't have the key. any sugestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your query :

```
databaseUser.child(userid).child(idorder)
```

instead use :

```
databaseOrder.child(userid).child(idorder)
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i got idOrder on status.setText ?

Comment: idorder what this provide you :?

Comment: in my database on dataorder i want to read all data inside. my way is just like i did on datauser, first i got the idUser then read the data, in this case i need idUser than idOrder and finaly can access the data. if my way is wrong can you tell me how, iam so new to this, sorry.

Comment: The way your trying to get idorder i think there will be more than orderid i suggest better put all those id in recyclerview

Comment: how ? arn't that gonna real all the data and all idOrder on dataorder ? because in my case i just need the data on idUser that currently log on.

Comment: just 1 actually, because my play is the orderid on each user gonna disapear on 24our time